# Is it possible to just compile new version of tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, virtualenv

I had built and installed a `Python2.7` locally in ubuntu 14.04. Since I upgrade my system to use `libtk8.6`, I would like to upgrade my tkinter version. However, I do not want to recompile and install all the packages from beginning.

Is it possible to just compile the tkinter against libtk8.6 and install it into current local Python environment?

Comment: Saying which operating system you are using might also be helpful...

Comment: @nbro thanks. I would like to see a solution regardless the OS since it is locally installed python not system-wide python. But I added the OS to allow more OS specified answer anyway.